# OpenCV: Error for failure to load library libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, homebrew

I am trying to set up openCV (installed with homebrew) on my mac and ran the following the command.

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) test.cpp -o Test& ./test
```

However, I got this error:

```
[1] 7834
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include/./test
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm not sure what to do take care of this issue very novice to openCV and C++.

The following shows the file structure. The test.cpp file is 2nd from the right along with the picture. I don't see how the program isn't finding the file as the name and location seem to be correct.

[image]

test.cpp:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    cout << "test output line" << endl;
     Mat img = imread("MyPic.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

     if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

     waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Took the .dylib files from `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib` duplicated and pasted them into `/usr/lib`.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary; `brew link opencv`, which is run after installation, should have made symlinks into /usr/local/lib for you. You might try  running the link step again (probably using --force) to make sure everything is in the right place. If you leave the files you copied in /usr/lib, Homebrew will be unable to upgrade them.

Comment: copy  /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.2.0/include/opencv  & opencv2 into /usr/local/include  too!

Answer (score 0):

copy all lib file ie in .dll format past it into your project folder.it will read all the neccessar file from that folder